# Unable to install MikTex on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: dns, latex

I'm trying to install MikTex on Ubuntu 20.04.3. In the step of updating (sudo apt-get update), I get the following error (Err:1 https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb focal InRelease Could not connect to ctan.mines-albi.fr:443 (194.167.201.52), connection timed out). However, the internet connection is good and the website is accessible. Then I couldn't finish the installation process. Note that I changed the DNS addresses to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and the error stills come out.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the installation directions on the site](https://miktex.org/download), you may need to change the line in your `miktex.list` file to this:

```
deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu focal universe
```

Then you can update apt and try the installation process

Comment: Thank you. Exactly that's what I have done. I followed the steps published on the MikTex website and I got the same error

Comment: What do you see when you put this in the Terminal ⇢ `sudo grep -rl "ctan.mines-albi.fr" /etc/apt`? This should say which file contains the bad source reference.

Comment: When I put sudo grep -rl "ctan.mines-albi.fr" /etc/apt in the terminal, nothing is come out. Then when I re-try the steps of installation, in the step of updating (sudo apt-get update), a note came out (N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'). After that I put sudo apt-get install miktex, the installation process runs normally. Thaaaaaaank you